# OpenMP: correct way to call nested functions

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

My code has the following structure. So basically I have some small functions, which are used later in a wrapper / bigger procedure and also used in main.

I would like to parallelise it with OMP. My naive approach would be to put
`#pragma omp parallel for` above each loop in the atomic functions. But this actually makes the code slower.

I assume, this is due to the fact, that each time I call one of the atomic functions in the wrapper, I do a lot of overhead.

But what is the correct way to do it?

```
void f1(vector& x, vector& y, double a, int N)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    y[i] = a * x[i];
}

void f2 /* similar loop over vectors */

void f3 /* also some loop over vector */


void wrapper()
{
   ..call f1..
   ..iterate with f2..
   ..call f3..
}

int main()
{
   ..call some f..
   ..call wrapper..
   ..call other f..
}
```

Comment: How big is `N`?

Comment: Assume something like 10^6

Comment: Why do you call them "atomic functions"? You should certainly avoid anything that is `atomic` in the technical sense.

Comment: OpenMP constructs have very little overhead. I once measured that I needed to execute an OpenMP loop hundreds of thousands of time before the overhead amounted to anything measurable.

Comment: atomic as in "small functions without dependencies being the building blocks of the code". I do not see how both comments are being helpful or guide me in any way.

Comment: Function `f1` can be easily vectorized and it is memory bound (not computation expensive) and I presume this is also the case in functions `f2` and `f3`. Generally, you cannot expect a big speedup in memory bound code (of course it depends on the hardware used). It seems that in your case the overhead of parallelization is bigger than the gain achieved by parallelization.

Comment: The parallelization could possibly take place where you "iterate with f2", but we need to know more about `f2` and what are these iterations.